# Actualizar ImageView desde un File

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de actualizar un `ImageView` desde un `File`, pero no lo consigo. Me explico:

Es una app sencilla que nada mas cargar busca una foto determinada en la tarjeta y la muestra. Eso lo hace genial. Al pulsar al boton para hacer una foto, la hago y la guarda bien, pero al volver a la actividad no la muestra. Claro, si salgo de la app y vuelvo, la foto nueva sí aparece. Por lo que creo que esa imagen se queda en memoria tal cual, pero no soy capaz de actualizarla en el momento. Les dejo el código a ver si se les ocurre algo:

```
   public class EditoNuevosClientes extends AppCompatActivity {
    int posicion;
    String id;
    ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;
    Cliente cliente=null;
    EditText txtnombre;
    EditText txttlf;
    EditText txtmail;
    EditText txtweb;
    File fichero;
    File foto;
    ImageView fotoNuevoCliente;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edito_nuevos_clientes);
        id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
        posicion=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("posicion");
        txtnombre=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtnombre);
        txttlf=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txttlf);
        txtmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtmail);
        txtweb=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtweb);
        fotoNuevoCliente=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fotoNuevoCliente);



        try{
             fichero=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones"+File.separator+id, "otrosClientes.txt");
            ObjectInputStream leo=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fichero));
            clientes=(ArrayList) leo.readObject();
            leo.close();
            cliente=clientes.get(posicion);

            txtnombre.setText(cliente.getNombre());
            txtnombre.setEnabled(false);
            txttlf.setText(cliente.getTlf());
            txtmail.setText(cliente.getEmail());
            txtweb.setText(cliente.getWeb());

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR DE LECTURA");
            Toast.makeText(this,"error de lectura",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

try{

     foto=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones"+File.separator+id, "fotoContactos"+File.separator+cliente.getNombre()+".jpg");

    if (foto.exists()){
        System.out.println("EXISTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");

        Picasso.with(this).load(foto).into(fotoNuevoCliente);

    }


}catch (Exception e){}


    }

    public void aceptar(View view){

        try{
            cliente.setNombre(txtnombre.getText().toString());
            cliente.setEmail(txtmail.getText().toString());
            cliente.setTlf(txttlf.getText().toString());
            cliente.setWeb(txtweb.getText().toString());
            ObjectOutputStream escribo=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fichero));
            escribo.writeObject(clientes);
            escribo.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("FALLO DE ESCRITURA");
        }

        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

    public void cancelar(View view){
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }

    public void foto(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Uri output = Uri.fromFile(foto);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        foto=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones"+File.separator+id, "fotoContactos"+File.separator+cliente.getNombre()+".jpg");
            if (foto.exists()){
            System.out.println("EXISTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
            Picasso.with(this).load(foto).into(fotoNuevoCliente);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: //1era vez:
foto = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones"+File.separator+id, "fotoContactos"+File.separator+cliente.getNombre()+".jpg");
Picasso.with(this).load(foto).into(fotoNuevoCliente);

//2da vez:
foto = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones"+File.separator+id, "fotoContactos"+File.separator+cliente.getNombre()+".jpg");
Picasso.with(this).load(foto).into(fotoNuevoCliente);

Estas llamando a la misma foto, es por eso que crees que no carga

Answer (score 0):

Cuando inicias la aplicación nuevamente, carga de la foto mediante `Picasso` porque esta definida al ingresar a tu `Activity`, en el método onCreate():

```
  foto=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones"+File.separator+id, "fotoContactos"+File.separator+cliente.getNombre()+".jpg");

if (foto.exists()){
    System.out.println("EXISTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");

    Picasso.with(this).load(foto).into(fotoNuevoCliente);

}
```

El problema que describes, sucede ya que en `onActivityResult()` estas creando un nuevo archivo:

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        fotoNuevoCliente.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        foto=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones"+File.separator+id, "fotoContactos"+File.separator+cliente.getNombre()+".jpg");
            if (foto.exists()){
            System.out.println("EXISTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
            //CARGANDO IMAGEN INCORRECTAMENTE!
            Picasso.with(this).load(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones"+File.separator+id, "fotoContactos"+File.separator+cliente.getNombre()+".jpg")).into(fotoNuevoCliente);
        }
    }
```

Debes simplemente cargar la imagen como lo realizas en `onCreate()`, ya que en este punto debe estar en disco creada:

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        fotoNuevoCliente.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        foto=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones"+File.separator+id, "fotoContactos"+File.separator+cliente.getNombre()+".jpg");
            if (foto.exists()){
            System.out.println("EXISTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
            //CARGANDO IMAGEN CORRECTAMENTE! =)
            Picasso.with(this).load(foto).into(fotoNuevoCliente);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Elena, lo he modificado tal y como me has dicho, lo he probado y sigue pasando lo mismo. Si salgo y vuelvo a entrar esta todo bien, pero nada mas volver de la foto no...Es como si la guardara en memoria.

Comment: Hola Sergio, verifica si entra en  System.out.println("EXISTEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"); dentro de onActivityResult(), comentame si es así.

Comment: confirmado que entra

Comment: Sergio!, Me refiero a el mensaje que esta dentro de onActivityResult , agrega este mensaje System.out.println("EXISTE en onActivityResult()");  para estar seguro!.

Comment: sisi elena, comprobado que entra ahi. Como digo es como si se guardara en memoria y no lo actualizara.... :S

Comment: El problema es que en realidad estas cargando la misma foto!

Comment: la foto que hago se llama igual pero es distinta. Quiero decir, la llamo siempre por ejemplo foto.jpg, pues al terminar de hacer la foto nueva, la he vuelto a llamar asi

Comment: En onActivityResult() en esta linea: foto=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Reuniones"+File.separator+id, "fotoContactos"+File.separator+cliente.getNombre()+".jpg"); Obtienes el mismo archivo que creaste y cargaste en onCreate().

Comment: Lo que tienes en otrosClientes.txt son las fotos que ya tienes guardadas en disco?

Comment: claro elena,cargo el mismo porque ese archivo ha sido modificado despues de la foto. Ese es el principal problema, que primero cargo un File, despues ese File ha sido modificado, pero al recargarlo sigue teniendo la imagen antigua. Por supuesto si reinicio la app,carga ese mismo File pero esta vez bien...

Comment: no, en ese txt hay datos de clientes

Answer (score 0):

A Picasso necesitas mandarle el Uri, no puedes mandarle la ruta sin convertirla mas o menos te explico:

Defines tus variable de Uri, y el control donde se va mostrar:

```
 Uri fileUriFoto; 
ImageView imgfoto;
```

Defines tu metodo para tomar la foto y asignar el URI mas o menos como ya lo tienes.

```
   File fileImage= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"folder");
  imagesFolder.mkdirs(); 

File image = new File(imagesFolder, "photo.jpg");

//Esta Uri es la misma que vas utilizar para mostrarla.
fileUriFoto = Uri.fromFile(image);

//Creas el intent y le mandas el uri que generaste
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUriFoto);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Defines tu onActivity for result.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //en caso de que sea una imagen capturada.
        if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {

                //Si se capturo la foto correctamente se muestra en el imageView

                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(fileUriFoto.getPath())
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .crossFade()
                        .into(imgFoto);



            }

       }
}
```

En este caso uso la libreria Glide para obtener la imagen, pero funciona igual para Picasso, Recuerda ponerle el URI y el getPath() para obtener la ruta y se muestre.